# Windows Application Preview Context menu in Electron

Tags: windows, electron

I'm working on an Electron 3+ Application in Windows. I'd like to add a context menu to the windows application preview as seen in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Visual Studio Code context menu]

I've already looked [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-taskbar) and the JumpList describes right clicking the windows icon in the tray and not the preview. And I've had no luck finding exactly what this is called so I can't even find any sort of documentation.

Does anyone know how I can add this into an Electron 3+ Application?

Comment: The right click of the preview is the same menu you get if you would click on a normal applications titlebar application. Its called the system menu. No clue on how to add to it in Electron tho, but perhaps that will start on you on the right direction.